# Why does my $instance within a custom widget return empty (undefined index)?

Tags: widgets

I'm trying to create an "About Me Widget", as follows:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: About Me Widget
*/

class Custom_About_Me_Widget extends Wp_Widget {

    /**
    * Setup the Widget
    */
    public function __construct() {

        $widget_ops = array('classname'     => 'widget-about-author',
                            'description'   => __('A widget to display information about an author.') 
                            );

        $control_ops = array('name'         => 'Enter your name...',
                             'description'  => 'Some words about you...'
                            );

        parent::__construct( '_s_about_me_widget', __('_s: About Me Widget', '_s_about_me_widget'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        $title              = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $image              = $instance['image'];
        $description        = $instance['description'];

        echo $before_widget;

        if( $title ) {
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        } else {
            echo 'Widget has no title!';
        } ?>

        <div class="about-widge">
            <?php if( $image ): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image );?>" alt="<?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?>"/>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( $description ): ?>
            <p><?php echo wp_kses_post( $description ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <?php

        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['title']          = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['image']          = strip_tags( $new_instance['image'] );
        $instance['description']    = $new_instance['description'];

        return $instance;
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $defaults = array(  'title'         => 'Your name here...',
                            'image'         => '',
                            'description'   => 'Enter some words about you...'
                        );

        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

        ?>
        <!-- Form for Title -->
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">Title:</label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title'];?>" />
        </p>

        <!-- Form for Image -->
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>">Title:</label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['image'];?>" />
        </p>

        <!-- Form for Description -->
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'description' ); ?>">Title:</label>
            <textarea id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'description' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'description' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['description'];?>" ?>
            </textarea>
        </p>

    <?php

    }
}
add_action( 'widget_init', 'Custom_About_Me_Widget');
register_widget( 'Custom_About_Me_Widget' );

?>
```

Unfortunately, this returns:

```
Notice
: Undefined index: title in
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\_s-master\inc\Widgets\widget_about-author-widget.php
on line
26
```

For each of the 3 indices: `title`, `image`, `description`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't "function widget( $args, $instance )" be "public function widget( $args, $instance )"? Reference: [WPBeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/)